# how handle ctrl-z within custom command-line interface?

Tags: signals, termios

I'm trying to make a command-line interface.  I want it to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  It handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> just fine.  For now, I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> twice, before it processes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  Here's the code that handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>:

```
            } else if (c == 26) { // ctrl-z
                resetTerminal();
                kill(getpid(), SIGTSTP);
                setTerminal();
```

I know why it has to be hit twice, but I'm not sure of what the solution is.  The code for resetTerminal() is:

```
void resetTerminal() {
    // reset terminal to the way it was
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &tty_old);
}
```

It reverts to the old terminal settings which voids:

```
tty_new.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG);
```

I'm not really sure how to make it so that I can revert to the old terminal settings and propagate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and suspend my program.

Any ideas?  Thanks.